Python - Is there a way to have my outlook signature added onto an automatic email draft
This is my code so far. The email is to use data from my df to write automatic emails. The email address is a field in the dataframe (defined  elsewhere)
import webbrowser
one_row = df_changes.iloc[0]
address = one_row['Address']
subject = address[:30] + '...' 

body = email_body.replace(' ', '%20').replace('\n','%0A') # Originally everything was on same line as mailto didnt recognise \n

webbrowser.open('mailto:?to=' + email_address + '&subject=' + subject + '&body=' + body, new=1)

It works, but is there a way include my outlook signature in this?
So far, I've asked microsoft copilot and it recommended using the win32 package but that seems to be a dead end.

Using mailto: won't give you any control over Outlook. You'll need to use Outlook's COM automation bindings:  Python can use Office's COM/Automation API, but the results aren't pretty: https://github.com/Hridai/Automating_Outlook

"but that seems to be a dead end." - can you elaborate?

@Dai With my limited skillset, I couldn't get it to do any more than using webbrower, and I felt that I had a better understanding of what webbrowser was doing
